# While writing struct objects to a file, does file extension matters?

Tags: c, file

Below code gives me interesting output in dat file as follows. I expected 0,and 0.0 in output.

```
                                        ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ                                                    ÌÌÌÌ
```

Also when I create a txt file instead of a dat file output becomes

NULL NULL NULL NULL ...

Why does it matter if I give a different extension to a file? Also why can't I get regular 0's and instead I and NULL?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct clientData{

int accountNo;
char firstName[20];
char lastName[20];
double balance;

};

int main(void){

int i;
FILE *ptrCrdFile;
struct clientData bankClient={0,"","",0.0};

ptrCrdFile=fopen("credits.dat","wb");

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    fwrite(&bankClient, sizeof(struct clientData), 1, ptrCrdFile);
}

fclose(ptrCrdFile);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What are the applications you use for dat and txt files?

Comment: You cannot in general serialize compound types in a predictable fashion. Serialize every field separately. Or try changing the struct to `{double, int, char[20], char[20]}`.

Comment: You won't be able to open your .dat file with Notepad++ or any other text editor because the file does not contain text but binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open your saved file (.txt or .dat, the extension doesn't matter) with a text editor, you need to write to the file using text output functions such as fprintf.

For example :

```
 ...
 for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {
   fprintf(ptrCrdFile, "%d\t%s\t%s\t%lf\n", bankClient.accountNo,  
           bankClient.firstName, bankClient.lastName, bankClient.balance);
 }
 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The extension of a file is just part of the name, and a convenience for the user. depending on the OS, it may be used to identify what application to use to open it, but that is unreliable. So in many cases the programs have code to detect the real format so they don't need to rely on the extension alone. i.e. Many movie players can open all kind of movie files playing the correctly, no matter if the extension is changed. For example, if you rename a movie from mpg4 to avi..

Answer (score 2):

The file extension is used to help the OS recognize the format of the data in it, but it does not modify its representation. Look at your file using a hexadecimal editor to find your data since you're writing "as-is".

```
                     "b" option for file output format :
```

> With the mode specifiers above the file is open as a text file. In order to open a file as a binary file, a "b" character has to be included in the mode string. This additional "b" character can either be appended at the end of the string (thus making the following compound modes: "rb", "wb", "ab", "r+b", "w+b", "a+b") or be inserted between the letter and the "+" sign for the mixed modes ("rb+", "wb+", "ab+").

For example, `struct clientData bankClient={5,"a","b",0.1};` gives you the following data :

(x86 plateform; little endian)

[image]

```
                           data representation :
```

- 5 -> `0x05 0x00 0x00 0x00` in little-endian
- `char[20]="a"` -> `0x61 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00`
- `char[20]="b"` -> `0x62 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00`
- `0.1` (64bits) -> `0000 0000 9a99 9999 9999 b93f` (look at [double floating-point representation])

Answer (score 1):

It is depending on the operating system and applications. Generally extension is part of file name used to identify the type of file quickly. Some application uses extension as mark to determine the file type quickly.